# HOW to show Select Input Method Dialog

Tags: android

Do u have any idea How to show Select Input Method Dialog in an Activity
I have been searching for it for hours and having no luck.
Any idea?

Comment: if one person preses the EditText View for almost 3-4 seconds then input dialog shows up automatically! do you want to show up that dilog on the click of some button?? please explain your question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Show select Input Method Dialog:

```
InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
im.showInputMethodPicker();
```

Comment: how to check which input method is currently activated

Comment: I searched but currently don't find any way to detect which input method is currently activated.

Answer (score 0):

Same answer but in **`Kotlin` single line** :

```
 (context.getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager).showInputMethodPicker()
```